# FFprobe command showing no output result

Tags: ffprobe

```
import subprocess 
filename = input('name of the file: ')     
class trial:

    def __init__(self):
        self.filename =filename

    def buildFFprobe(self):
        self.commandlist = ["ffprobe", "show_entries", 
        "stream=codec_type", "start_time", "- v", "-of", 
        "compact=p=1:nk=0", self.filename]
    
        return

    def runFFprobe(self):
        self.buildFFprobe()
        print(self.commandlist)

object = trial()
object.runFFprobe()
```

// I have corrected the initial code with 'self.filename' to self.filename now it prints the commandlist with proper input file. But it fails me why no output result is generated. A review of the code is appreciated if anybody got the time. //

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: You don't see the code that is written, what else is it if not programming?
I want to program a script that tells me information about video files whenever I execute it. It may not be flashy but I wanted it to write it for my own reason.

Comment: Which programming language is that? Also, did you try to run `ffprobe` manually? Does this work, but the version from the script does not? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: The script I am writing is based on python and yes if I type the command in windows terminal FFprobe works just fine. The command I have posted is copied from the python script which is not showing any output. The command for windows terminal is // ffprobe -show_entries stream=codec_type,start_time -v 0 -of compact=p=1:nk=0 movie.mkv //

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: "why this code is not working" - what does that mean? What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: What I mean by my 'code not working' is I am not getting the output result from the code. FFprobe should give me the codec type of the video file as well as the starting time   of all the streams(video, audio, subtitles) in the file. I tried to change the code and researched a bit which led me to this stage. The script is not showing me errors which makes it difficult for me to identify the problem. If you can run my mode and see for yourself that might help.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: I have corrected the initial code with 'self.filename' to self.filename now it prints the commandlist with proper input file. But it fails me why no output result is generated. A review of the code is appreciated if anybody got the time.